# How do I estimate hosting costs (AWS) for MeteorJS apps?

Tags: meteor

I deployed my meteor app to AWS and I'm still using the free tire. I don't understand how the cost is calculated. 
Now I'm expecting more users and I need to know how much it will cost me per user.

Comment: You can't say this unless you have some reliable performance metrics of your app. If you have implemented efficient algorithms it will be less resource consuming than by using inefficient algorithms. Please provide some performance specs of your app, for example in context of a specific use case.

Comment: @Jankapunkt I don't have any performance monitoring tool installed at the moment. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: No worries you can do some research in the meteor forums and keep this question open. Once you have collected some metrics for your app, you can edit this question with some more information.

Comment: How many users do you expect ? kadira apm is a good performance monitoring tool : https://github.com/lmachens/meteor-apm-server

Comment: @Victor it's hard to tell how much to expect at the moment. I will try kadira apm thank you

Comment: You also can try this one http://montiapm.com as kadira apm replacement.

Comment: @ivan133 looks promising. Definitely will try it thank you